# TYPO3 getting image from page content

Tags: image, get, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I'm working on my first TYPO3 project and I'm done with the template, I just can't figure out how to make this work:

My page content is one column with header, text and title in every field.
I don't have any problems showing header and text on my website, but the image just won't work.
My image-path is fileadmin/user_upload/ and I can show it by setting the filename in my code, but thats obviously not what I want.
This is my Content Object Array, the code for the image is one of the versions I found when searching, but none of them worked:

```
page.20 = CONTENT
page.20.table = tt_content
page.20.wrap = <div id="content">|</div>

page.20.renderObj = COA
page.20.renderObj.wrap = <div id="news">|</div>
page.20.renderObj {

  10 = TEXT  
  10.stdWrap.field = header
  10.stdWrap.wrap = <div id="newstitle"><span>|</span></div>

  20 = IMAGE
  20.stdWrap.field = image
  20.stdWrap.wrap = <div id="newsimage><img src="fileadmin/user_upload/|"</img></div>

  30 = TEXT  
  30.stdWrap.field = bodytext
  30.stdWrap.wrap = <div id="newstext"><p>|</p></div>
}
```

Hope someone could help me out, so I can finally finish this project!

Comment: Let me understand: you have contents in your column and want display them just on the page right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understood correctly, but... you don't need to write it yourself, just in your main TS template include `CSS Styled Content` from extension, so you can render whole column like:

```
page.20 < styles.content.get
```

If you need to change some wrappings (i.e.: to add your ***news*** CSS classes) you can also override them in `setup` field.

edit: Go to **Templates** > **Template analyzer** and check the **EXT:css_styled_content/static/** code to find declaration you'd like to change (prepare for looong reading ;)) when you finally find it, just you can overwrite it in your TS, ie: to wrap text section of **Text w/ image** CE you can use:

```
tt_content.textpic.20.text.wrap = <div class="myNewsClass"> | </div>
```

Finally I'd suggest not to replace original classes but **add** your own so the above sample would be like:

```
tt_content.textpic.20.text.wrap = <div class="csc-textpic-text myNewsClass"> | </div>
```

de facto all these classes *csc-* has some CSS default styling therefore you can choose to align the image to the left or right (etc) out of the box. If you'll remove it you'll need to handle these things yourself.

Comment: All right, I guess I didn't quite get the documentation then.
Could you explain how exactly I can wrap the specific elements of the page content then? Don't really understand that yet.

Comment: First of all thanks for your help, it cleared a lot for me. 
I kinda feel stupid asking, but I still don't how to wrap the header, text and image section individually.

Comment: Ok I'm kinda messing up the formatting here and then I'm too slow with editing my comment T_T. So heres the rest:

I found the CType: textpic section and I find your example of the text wrapping and I suppose the dataWrap is for the header, but how do I wrap my image then?

Sorry if I'm asking stupid stuff, but I'm really new to that.

Comment: Nevermidn me and my stupid questions, I figured that I tried to do everything way too complicated! Got it now :D